# Pause after any program/script completion in `screen` term emulator

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

`Press any key to continue...` appeared after any program/script termination in the `screen` program. How to remove this?

Comment: can you post some of your code? this happens when using the `read -p` command

Comment: I start the emacs from mc, then exit emacs, and this message appears.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: is it `screen` or `mc`?

Comment: That message is probably there for a reason (in case you have a terminal without the a working -hold argument like rxvt).  If it were not there, a command like: `echo $DISPLAY` would flicker a terminal and exit.  If you still wish to remove it look for something like read -p "Press any key to continue" in your /etc/profile, $HOME/.bashrc and possibly the sources of screen... instead you can add on a -hold arg to $TERM in its place (btw, if you do that though, your next question would likely be "How do I get all these terminals to exit without having to type exit")

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It happens when I run mc from screen and execute a command in a panel mode of mc (say echo foo). If I do the same but from plain xterm without screen, then there is no "press any key to continue" message. (my system is Debian Squeeze)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set   F9 -> "Options" -> "Configuration" -> "Pause after run" to "Never" in your mc
(so not to make a pause on dumb terminals).
This helps for me.